How to contact the extension owner of the Yarn@2 Azure Pipelines task to get an updated version of the task?
An Azure DevOps pipeline using the yarn@2 task reports the following warning:

##[warning]Task 'Yarn task' version 2 (Yarn@2) is dependent on a Node version (6) that is end-of-life. Contact the extension owner for an updated version of the task. Task maintainers should review Node upgrade guidance: https://aka.ms/node-runner-guidance .

How to get an upgraded version of the task to avoid this warning ? Is there a risk that the yarn@2 task will break or will be retired at some point of time ?

This warning will not impact the task to run as normal.
Currently, the latest version of this task is Yarn@3. You can uninstall the old version of Yarn extension and then reinstall it from Marketplace into your Azure DevOps organization. After this, you should be able use the Yarn@3 task.
Note:
The Yarn@3 task is using Node version 10 which also is end-of-life. So, you also will get the similar warning in your pipeline runs. And the warning will not impact the task to run as normal.
There is an existing ticket has reported this issue in the GitHub repository of this extension (see geeklearningio/gl-vsts-tasks-yarn#117). You can follow this issue ticket and add your comments on it.

EDIT:
As we discussed in the comments, as an alternative, you can use the script tasks (such as Bash, PowerShell, CmdLine, etc..) to execute the yarn commands, as long as the Yarn tool has been installed on the agent machine.
See below example as reference:
steps:
# Install the latest Node.js which also contains npm to install.
- task: UseNode@1
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
  inputs:
    version: '>10.x'
    checkLatest: true

# Use npm to install Yarn and update Yarn to the latest stable version.
- bash: |
    npm install --global yarn
    yarn set version stable
    yarn --version
  displayName: 'Install Yarn'

- bash: |
    yarn xxx
    yarn xxx
  displayName: 'Execute some Yarn commands'




Thanks a lot for the quick ans helpfull answer! Given the lack of traction on maintainng this third-party extension (last commit 3 years ago), Is there any alternative (e.g. a bash task to setup and use a more recent yarn utility version) ?

@PhilippeLaloum, Yes, you also can use the built-in script tasks (such as Bash, PowerShell, etc..) to execute the yarn commands just like you execute the commands using a command prompt on your local machine, as long as the Yarn tool has been installed on the agent machine.

@PhilippeLaloum, I have updated my answer with more information about how to install the latest Node tool (Node.js) and Yarn tool on the agent machine, and how to call the yarn commands using a script task (e.g., bash). See EDIT.

@PhilippeLaloum, Have you tried the workaround shared above? Is it working for you?

Thanks a lot for the updated answer; the alternative you've proposed is working for me and I would progressively migrate my existing pipelines for using it.
